# Is it necessary to connect wearable to handheld through android wear companion app to use data layer API?

Tags: android, wear-os

Is it necessary to connect wearable to handheld through android wear companion app to use data layer API ?﻿
Manually, I paired wearable with device and I tried using wearable data layer API but it is not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's necessary.

The Wear system is the foundation for the Data API. If the two devices aren't showing as connected in the companion app, then the API won't function.